# Integers, GCF and train schedules

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found an exercise which asks the following:

> A train leaves every 7 hours from the Moscow station. Prove that it is possible to catch it eventually at 9am.

The answer, as given in the book:

Notice that 24 and 7 are coprime, so that GCD(24,7) = 1. Therefore, $\exists m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$$7m = 1 - 24n$$

At this point, the author claims that this means that if the train leaves at the $k$th hour, then $m$ trains later, the departure time will be $k+1$. I have no problem with the mathematics, but I'm having difficulties interpreting the result.

If the train leaves at time $k$, then $m$ trains later, it will leave at $k + 7m = k + 1 - 24n$. Since we have period of 24 hours, $k+1 - 24n  \equiv k+1 \pmod {24} $.

Is this the correct interpretation? I think the reason why I find so difficult is because we are not working in $[0,1,\ldots23]$, but instead over the integers, and then translating over to mod 24.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: But we are working in $[0,1,\ldots 23]$  If you just ignore the date and only look at the hour, that is exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that there is no "24th hour", so we're effectively working in $[0,1,...,23]$...

Now, the equation you derived,
$$k+7m=k+1-24n,$$
does mean that after the $m$th train, $1-24n \pmod{24}=1$ hours will have gone by, as expected.

Comment: I remember a similar problem that I couldn't solve in middle school about clocks and the position of their hands... This sort of problem has been throwing me off ever since I can remember ! Thank you for the answer, I just wanted to make sure I was understanding this correctly